# Can I run Odoo 10 directly from his source code?

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to run Odoo 10 community on Ubuntu 14.04 from nightly source files.

Everywhere on the web, it is written to run Odoo 10 in a terminal with the command **./odoo-bin**.

But I don't see this file in the downloaded source files.

Where is it???

Should I inevitably run an installation script? (I prefer not)

Should I inevitably run the **setup.py** file to build or install the source code? I didn't have to do that with Odoo 8 to obtain **openerp-server** file...

I don't want to run odoo10 like a service. Not now.

Comment: I think the book "Odoo 10 Development Essentials"
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/odoo-10-development/9781785884887/ Chapter 1 :
Install Odoo from source code and use all the basic techniques to setup and manage your Odoo server instances Can help you, I'm reading it now. And I hope this comment won't be deleted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the "odoo" folder.

just cd to the main source folder, and execute the command.

$ ./odoo/odoo-bin

I have tested it on my service.

Answer (score 0):

the file setup/odoo is the same as odoo-bin 
you can run odoo by ./setup/odoo
if you find errors of imports move de file odoo from setup to the main folder (ex : odoo-server) and run it

if you use eclipse 
you can make eclipse recognize the file odoo just by adding the extension .py (odoo ==> odoo.py)